# A linear transfomation is onto if and only if

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So I know that the tranformed matrix will go from 3 columns to two columns. But I'm not quite sure how any determination of onto-ness can be determined without knowing what that transformation is, better yet finding how k will influence that.

Comment: The image of $x\mapsto Ax$ is equal to the column space of $A$.  In particular, the *dimension* of the image is equal to the dimension of the column space (AKA column rank).

Answer (score 1):

The function $T$ is onto if and only if its rank is equal to $2$, i.e. the dimension of $\Bbb R^2$. and this is true if and only if the two vectors $\vec u=-2\vec i+\vec j+2\vec k$ and $ \vec v=3\vec i-1.5\vec j+(k-11)\vec k$ are linearly independent. If we make $$\vec v=\lambda \vec u$$ we find
the scalar $$\lambda=-1.5=\frac{k-11}{2}$$
 Hence we have $k=8$ and the vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are linearly dependent. When $k\ne 8$, the system is not compatible so these vectors are linearly independent and $T$ is onto. Thus

$$T \text{ is onto } \iff k\ne 8$$